# Simple Python List Concatenation

Tags: python

I have a list of strings, with each string as a character. They're in order of the word. How do I put each character all together in one string. Example:

```
list_characters = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

To become:

```
'Hello'
```

Please help and thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [1]: s = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']

In [2]: ''.join(s)
Out[2]: 'Hello'
```

The `join` method is a bit different from others you may be familiar with in that you put the element you want to use to 'join` the elements together first, and then call the method on that. Here are some more examples:

```
In [4]: print '\n'.join(s)
H
e
l
l
o

In [5]: ' '.join(s)
Out[5]: 'H e l l o'

In [6]: 'GOODBYE'.join(s)
Out[6]: 'HGOODBYEeGOODBYElGOODBYElGOODBYEo'
```

The `join` method accepts any 'iterable', which is anything you can 'iterate' over (such as a list, as in your example). Strings themselves are also iterables, so you could even do this:

```
In [7]: s = 'Hello'

In [8]: 'Z'.join(s)
Out[8]: 'HZeZlZlZo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I highly recommend the join() method as mentioned by RocketDonkey above, another way would be this:

```
reduce(lambda acc,x:acc+x,['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join()` to concatenate all the elements of list into a string like this:

```
test = ['H', 'e', 'l' 'l', 'o']
''.join(test)
```

If you want to join with '-' character in between them, use this:

```
   test = ['H', 'e', 'l' 'l', 'o']
   '-'.join(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the elements of list into a string by various methods:

1. By iterating through the list

```
str=""
for i in list:
    str+=i
print(str)      #hello
```

2. Using built in function 'join()'

```
list = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
str=""
print("".join(list))       #hello
```

3. Using list comprehension

```
str = "".join([str(elem) for elem in list]) 
print(str)       #hello
```

4. Using map() function

```
str = ''.join(map(str, list)) 
print(str)       #hello
```

#Note: Last two methods can be used in case you have int elements also,
as Python doesn't allow concatenation of elements with different data types.